# Copy a list from one file to another (python)

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I am trying to take input values from a GUI (made with tkinter) and pass it along to another file.

I have created a file called FileA (where the tkinter code is) and created a list "set1" in the file.

```
set1=[12,23,34]
```

This list is simply appended with the values taken as input from the tkinter GUI. I want to copy this set1 to another file called FileB and process it there.

I created a function in FileA to try and take global variables:

```
set1=[12,23,34]

ab = set1[-3]
cd = set1[-2]
ef = set1[-1]

def take1():
        set21 = []
        global ab
        global cd
        global ef
        set21.append(ab)
        set21.append(cd)
        set21.append(ef)
        return set21
```

In FileB, I use:

```
import FileA
FileA.take1()
```

But I am getting an error:

> name 'ab' is not defined

Why is this happening? Is there any other (simpler?) way to copy a whole list from one file to another?

Answer (score 1):

If you’re trying to get `set1` in `FileB` then you can directly get it since it's a global variable. Here's an example:

FileB:

```
import FileA
FileA.set1
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do this without it automatically triggering the FileA? It has a GUI that opens up every time I try this?

Comment: It should work. It’s probably code that is accidentally called. If you have some "global" code hat initiates that GUI, then make sure to put it in a `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Answer (score 0):

This works fine with me so I suggest the error is somewhere else in your code.

To get the list from one file you can simply do:

```
import FileA
set1 = FileA.set1
```

Comment: Hi. This seems to work. The problem was that I was using Jupyter notebook, and the Jupyer file extension. 

I have a different but related problem now. When I import the whole FileA, it gets executed again. It has many different executables which are getting re-executed when I import FileA in FileB. 

Is there a way to call the set from a function of the FileA without it rerunning?